# How can I make an environment like the one in the image in beamer-metropolis?

Tags: beamer, environments, beamer-metropolis

I am using the metropolis theme and I want to make an environment like the one in the image. It's my first time creating an environment so I'm not sure where to start, any help would be wonderful. The colors are the ones used by metropolis.[image]